# Can't get nested model value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I want to create `Buyer` and `Seller` model that can be authenticated by `devise`.

#### app/models/buyer.rb

```
class Buyer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as: :authable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

#### app/controllers/buyers_controller.rb

```
class BuyersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @buyer = Buyer.new
    @buyer.build_user
  end
  def create
    @buyer = Buyer.new(buyer_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @buyer.save
        format.html { redirect_to @buyer, notice: 'Buyer was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @buyer }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @buyer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
   def buyer_params
      params.require(:buyer).permit(user_attributes: [:email, :password, :password_confirmation])
    end
end
```

#### app/views/buyers/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@buyer) do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for @buyer.user do |user| %>
        <%= user.email_field :email %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

With these codes I can create a `Buyer` but the buyer doesn't have a user.

It seems I'm writing wrong way in `permit`

```
>> params
=> {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xxx", "buyer"=>{"user"=>{"email"=>"bar@example.com"}}, "commit"=>"Create Buyer", "controller"=>"buyers", "action"=>"create"}
>>  buyer_params
=> {}
```

If I change `user_attributes` to `user`, I can get `email` parameter, but then I get a error: `User(#70323929049400) expected, got ActionController::Parameters(#70323888554040)`.

How can I fix this error?

#### Edit

Thanks for Brian's help I could remove the error by:

```
def buyer_params
  params[:buyer][:user_attributes] = params[:buyer][:user] if params[:buyer][:user].present?
  params.require(:buyer).permit(user_attributes: [:email, :password, :password_confirmation])
end
```

But I don't think this is a right way to write. I create a repository for it. I'm happy if you can check it.

https://github.com/ironsand/polymorphic-authable-by-devise

What I did was:

1. create the App.
2. create User model by devise.
3. create Seller and Buyer model by scaffold.
4. Both model have a User as `authable`.

Answer (score 1):

I could be misreading the issue, but it appears 'accepts_nested_attributes_for' requires :user_attributes but the form is return a :user. One (perhaps inelegant) solution would be to do something like this:

```
def buyer_params
  params[:user_attributes] = params[:user] if params[:user].present?
  params.require(:buyer).permit(user_attributes: [:email, :password, :password_confirmation])
end
```

Assuming this works and you apply similar similar code to create Sellers, a word of warning is the same User may not be able to be both a Buyer and a Seller.

Comment: Thanks I could get by `params[:buyer][:user_attributes] = params[:buyer][:user] if params[:buyer][:user].present?`, but I don't think this is right way to go. I created a repository for this matter. Probably I miss something very basic. I'm very thankful if you check the code shortly.

Comment: Thanks for the repository; made it easier to see what is going on! Try using this in your form:   <%= f.fields_for :user do |user| %> (and remove the extra line I had suggested earlier)

Comment: Are your Buyers and Sellers always Users, or are you inserting buyers and sellers that may or may not be users? If the former, both solutions Rich provides conveys that better than accepts_nested_attributes_for does. If the latter, you will want to retain the separate models as you are doing. The other question you should ask yourself is whether a user can be both a buyer and a seller. If so, you can't use STI (easily) but could use Rich's role suggestion but make it a has_many relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Better idea...

Why don't you either set `roles` or have [`STI`](http://samurails.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1/) on a single `User` model?

Although you can have separate models for Devise, in your case, it seems somewhat unnecessary, especially as you're associating `Buyer belongs_to User`...

It will be much more efficient if you populate the `User` model through `Devise`, and extrapolate through either `roles` or `STI` functionality:

---

**STI**

[Here's a tutorial with EXACTLY this functionality](http://adamrobbie.me/blog/2013-3-29-sti-with-rails-40-beta-and-devise).

You could set up an STI relatively simply:

```
#app/models/buyer.rb
class Buyer < User
end

#app/models/seller.rb
class Seller < User
end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   #Devise stuff here
end
```

You'll then be able to use the models as if they had their own tables...

```
@buyer = Buyer.find params[:id]
@buyer.email
```

This will allow you to set up the forms and controllers necessary to facilitate the signup process for either buyers or sellers...

```
#config/routes.rb
devise_for :users,   skip: :registrations
devise_for :sellers, skip: :sessions
devise_for :buyers,  skip: :sessions

#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :type
   end
end
```

---

**Roles**

Another method is to [use *roles*](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-a-default-role-to-a-User).

We use this a lot - set a `role_id` in the `users` table to give them certain privileges:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :role_id
   end
end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   ## Devise Stuff ##
   before_create :set_role
   belongs_to :role

   private

   def set_role
      self.role = Role.find_by(name: "buyer") unless role?
   end
end
```

--

I think your current setup is highly inefficient to the point of it hampering future extensibility.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I know about STI and I've created this app as a example of the problem, my real project have many columns already that are different `Buyer` and `Seller`.

Answer (score 0):

When using nested attributes, you must pass the name of the association to `fields_for`, in your case:

```
 <%= fields_for :user do |user|
    ...
 <% end %>
```